# What is this flute inscription?

Tags: translation

A saw this inscription on a flute. Can someone tell what does it is? 
I'm really curious. 
Thanks in advance.

[image: Inscription]

Comment: bkrs has a forum for recognizing (deciphering) text images https://bkrs.info/taolun/forum-51.html

Comment: request has been submitted, please watch https://bkrs.info/taolun/forum-51.html for result (expect Chinese text)

Comment: This is just the full text of a poem by 高適 called 塞上聽吹笛. No need to submit to a forum...

Comment: anyhow, note speedy reply: 雪净胡天牧马还，月明羌笛戌楼间。
借问梅花何处落？风吹一夜满关山！ (

Comment: Please use original text...雪淨胡天牧馬還，月明羌笛戍樓間。借問梅花何處落，風吹一夜滿關山。

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.
I have read many interesting things and with this i can finally say that i'm going to start learning chinese.
Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The full text is:

> ## 高適《塞上聽吹笛》
>
> 雪淨胡天牧馬還
>
> 月明羌笛戍樓間
>
> 借問梅花何處落
>
> 風吹一夜滿關山

Please note that the other proposed answer in the comments, apart from rendering the text in Simplified Chinese, also incorrectly identified the character「戍」as「戌」.